# What does this FTC scenario actually represent?

Tags: calculus

**Expounding on this question from my other thread**
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_1^2t^2dt$$

I want to understand what something like this represents (if anything), or if  this is just a theoretical construct to prove some larger point.  What does this mean?

Well, let's say my salary is modeled by $f(t)=t^2$

That means the instantaneous rate of change (derivative) of my salary is modeled by $g(t)=2t$

So, what exactly does the below expression represent?   Definite integral calculates the area under the rate curve on [2,3] = the total salary change over [2,3]?  So, the salary grew by 5 on [2,3]
$$\int_2^32tdt=[3^2-2^2]=5$$

This means area under the rate curve on [2,x] = the total salary change over [2,x]?
$$\int_2^x2tdt=??$$

But now, what does **this** expression below represent?   Why would you take the derivative of the above?  Also, should it be $\frac{d}{dt}$ or $\frac{d}{dx}$ ?  Is the below the rate of change of the total salary change?

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_2^x2tdt=??$$

Comment: The integral is a constant. The derivative of a constant is $0$.

Comment: Fixed it.  Got an answer for my actual question?

Comment: The **derivative** with respect to $x$ of $\int_2^x 2t\,dt$ is, by the FTC (short), or direct computation of the integral, and then differentiation (longer) is $2x$. The integral from $2$ to $3$ is unchangingly $5$, so its derivative with respect to any variable $y$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${d\over dt}\int_1^2 t^2\,dt={d\over dt}\left[{t^3\over 3}\right]\Bigg|_{t=1}^{t=2}={d\over dt}\left[{2^3\over 3}-{1^3\over 3}\right]={d\over dt}\left[{7\over 3}\right]=0.$$

This should not be surprising since $\int_1^2 t^2\,dt$ is a constant, so ${d\over dt}\int_1^2 t^2\,dt={d\over dt}(\text{constant})=0$.

On the other hand, ${d\over dt}\int_1^t x^2\,dx$ is a different animal, but one that makes perfect sense calculationally since
$${d\over dt}\int_1^t x^2\,dx={d\over dt}\left[{x^3\over 3}\right]\Bigg|_{x=1}^{x=t}={d\over dt}\left[{t^3\over 3}-{1^3\over 3}\right]=t^2,$$
(of course, we could have appealed to the other part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get this immediately, but that is a different point) and this says that **the (instantaneous) rate of change of the function $A(t):=\int_1^t x^2\,dx$ is $A'(t)=t^2$.** Functions of this form $A(t)$ are sometimes called *accumulator functions* since they are tracking, in this case, the accumulated (signed) area under $y=x^2$ from $x=1$ to $x=t$ (which is varying).

More generally, for
$$
A(t):=\int_a^t f(x)\,dx,
$$
then 
$$
A'(t)={d\over dt}\int_a^t f(x)\,dx,
$$
represents the **rate of change of the accumulated area under $f(x)$ from $a\le x\le t$.**

We can ask all the usual calculus question about this "new" class of functions: when is the accumulated area increasing? decreasing? when it is maximum/minimum?

Comment: This was a nice explanation.  I have revisited this and this was my intuition this time.   It is the rate of change of the area under the curve.  This of course depends on x.   For a simply $x^2$ function, the rate of change of the accumulated area depends on x.

Comment: Anyone know an example of something you'd actually model like this?  Wanting to know the rate of change of the accumulated amount (represented by the integral).    How does the rate of change of the accumulation (or total) vary as x varies, etc?

Comment: @JackOfAll Sure, here are a few example applications. (1) Imagine water flowing into a container at a nonuniform rate $r(t)$. Then $\int_0^t r(x)\,dx$ would represent the net amount accumulated in the container over the time interval $[0,t]$. (2) Imagine a particle moves along a line with velocity $v(t)$. Then $\int_0^t v(x)\,dx$ represents the net displacement of the particle over the interval $[0,t]$. Moreover, $\int_0^t |v(x)|\,dx$ represents the total distance the particle travels over $[0,t]$.